# JavaScript – Problems with Reset button on calculator

Tags: javascript

I have a simple calculator and I want two text fields to reset when the reset button is clicked, but for some reason it's not working. I've referenced other Stack Overflow inquiries, but some use jQuery. Is there a way to do this without jQuery? Anyways, here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jsdmLr7b/

```
<script>
    var a, b, result;

    function setValues() {
        a = Number(document.getElementById('leftInput').value);
        b = Number(document.getElementById('rightInput').value);
    }

    function sum() {
        setValues();
        result = a + b;
        document.getElementById('inputTotal').innerHTML = result;
    }

    function reset() {
        document.getElementByID('inputLeft').innerHTML.value = "";
        document.getElementByID('inputRight').innerHTML.value = "";
    }
</script>
<div>
    <input id="leftInput" type="text" />
    <input id="rightInput" type="text" />
    <input type="button" onClick="sum()" value="sum" />
    <input type="button" onClick="reset()" value="reset" />
    <p>Total: <a id="inputTotal"></a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: remove innerHTML in your reset function. Simply use value, should do the trick.

Comment: @fubbe Thanks! That worked. What's the point of the innerHTML tag?

Comment: value is the attribute of the input type text element. While innerHTML is mainly used to alter the DOM. Take a look at it on w3c or mdn. Don't forget to accept @Kyle's answer, vote him up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
    var a, b, result;

    function setValues() {
        a = Number(document.getElementById('leftInput').value);
        b = Number(document.getElementById('rightInput').value);
    }

    function sum() {
        setValues();
        result = a + b;
        document.getElementById('inputTotal').innerHTML = result;
    }

    function reset() {
        document.getElementById("leftInput").value = "";
        document.getElementById("rightInput").value = "";
    }
</script>
<div>
    <input id="leftInput" type="text" />
    <input id="rightInput" type="text" />
    <input type="button" onClick="sum()" value="sum" />
    <input type="button" onClick="reset()" value="reset" />
    <p>Total: <a id="inputTotal"></a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Your problem was that you were calling getElementByID on the document. The proper way to call this is getElementById with a lowercase "d" in "Id."

Also, you were referencing the wrong id values. They are leftInput and rightInput, not inputLeft and inputRight. It can be easy to overlook wording and case sensitivity after looking at code for hours!

I switched the reset function to use `.value = "";` because it makes more sense in this case and should be used for input/form operations, while innerHTML is used for other elements (div, span, td, etc.)

**You can also clear your total by adding this to the reset() function:**

```
document.getElementById("inputTotal").innerHTML = "";
```

In this case you want to use innerHTML because your value is not inside an input/form operation. Here's the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsdmLr7b/1/).

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to reset the total value after it's calculated?

Answer (score 0):

I Found A Very Simple Solution Just Wrap Your All Input in FORM Tag and Your Reset button will work Fine